# Alias A Subquery Inside CASE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a simple `INSERT` query which also contains the following code for one of the columns values.

```
VALUES( ..... ,
CASE WHEN hand < (SELECT AVG(ss.hand) AS r FROM sales ss WHERE ss.year=:year)
     THEN (r - hand)
     ELSE 0
     END)";
```

The goal here is to use the subquery result average (aliased as 'r') inside the `THEN`. Problem is, I'm getting an error saying the column r was not found when running the query. If I remove the 'r' from the THEN, it runs fine. I don't want to duplicate the sub query into the `THEN` since this would harm the performance.

I've also tried to alias the whole subquery, but that caused a syntax error.

Any hints on this? I'm new to SQL and have been struggling with this for hours now.

Comment: User variable `SET @var:=your subquery` then reuse it.

Comment: Where can I put the SET? I've tried and got another syntax error.

Comment: Outside the main query,its a separate query.

Comment: Problem is, I want to use this in a similar UPDATE query as well, where "year" changes between rows and therefor, the result of the subquery changes as well. Declaring it outside the main query would give me only a single result for all the rows (I suppose?) Thanks for your help, by the way

Comment: @Eran: you can't, but you can use derived tables or CTEs to achieve a similar goal.

Comment: Here is `hand` defined?

Comment: 'hand' is part of the input (it's supposed to be :hand, actually)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to repeat the expression:

```
(CASE WHEN hand < (SELECT AVG(ss.hand) FROM sales ss WHERE ss.year=:year)
     THEN ((SELECT AVG(ss.hand) FROM sales ss WHERE ss.year=:year) - hand)
     ELSE 0
 END)
```

You could also express this as:

```
greatest(0, (SELECT AVG(ss.hand) FROM sales ss WHERE ss.year=:year) - hand) )
```

Another alternative is to use `select . . . insert` and define this expression in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks! This greatest operator seems like just what I needed. I'll check this out and approve the answer if everything is fine. Thanks